# Dragging files into rich textbox to read text in file

Tags: c#, .net, drag-and-drop, text-files, richtextbox

I'm having a problem with dragging and dropping files onto a richTextBox, every time I drag a text file onto it, it turns into a picture of the text file with its name under it. Double click the file and it opens up using the system default application (ie notepad for text files, etc). basically its making shortcuts in the richTextBox, when i want it to read the text in the file.

Based on this code, the text from the file **should** extract into richTextBox1

```
    class DragDropRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
    public DragDropRichTextBox()
    {
        this.AllowDrop = true;
        this.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop);
    }

    private void DragDropRichTextBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] fileNames = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];

        if (fileNames != null)
        {
            foreach (string name in fileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(name) + "\n");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: set the Property EnableAutoDragDrop = False; Becasue of that you got the Icon in RicHTextBox, Follow the Event Handler in my answer . It will work

Comment: Sorry about that, added the lines to Designer.cs and it works, thanks

Comment: make as answer please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to check the draged object before you are reading into file. try below code.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            richTextBox1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(richTextBox1_DragDrop);
            richTextBox1.AllowDrop = true;
        }

        void richTextBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            object filename = e.Data.GetData("FileDrop");
            if (filename != null)
            {
                var list = filename as string[];

                if (list != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(list[0]))
                {
                    richTextBox1.Clear();
                    richTextBox1.LoadFile(list[0], RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I received three errors. two on this line of code `if (e.KeyStates == DragDropKeyStates.ShiftKey)` one under `KeyStates` and one under `DragDropKeyStates`. and with this code `System.Windows.Documents.TextRange range;` under `Documents`

Comment: as in `using System.Windows.Forms;` yes

Comment: give me 5 min.Will update my code for WinForms. this code belongs to WPF.

Comment: Wow I'm amazed! Your method opens up large text files 3x faster than notepad! +1 for this method

Answer (score 3):

use this to bind **DragEnter** and **DragDrop** event for RichTextBox in **Designer.cs**

```
 this.richTextBox1.AllowDrop = true; this.richTextBox1.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.textBox1_DragDrop); this.richTextBox1.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.textBox1_DragEnter);

private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    Array a = (Array)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                    if (a != null)
                    {
                        string s = a.GetValue(0).ToString();
                        this.Activate();
                        OpenFile(s);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error in DragDrop function: " + ex.Message);
                }

            }

            private void OpenFile(string sFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    StreamReader StreamReader1 = new StreamReader(sFile);
                    richTextBox1.Text = StreamReader1.ReadToEnd();
                    StreamReader1.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error loading from file");
                }

            }

            private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                else
                    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

            }
```

Comment: There is no "AllowDrop". This is a rich text box. The closest there is "EnableAutoDragDrop" which is already set to true

Comment: You are using  txtFileContent to Drag and Drop, AllowDrop is property availlable for TextBox. Please check the Property for TextBox. your code is working fine. Only thing is need to Write events for DragEnter and Set Property True for AllowDrop  txtFileContent

Comment: There is no "AllowDrop" as I said this is a rich text box. Yes code is working, but for a regular textbox. I modified it because i need it to work with richTextBox, which it doesn't

Comment: then what you mean by this event txtFileContent_DragDrop.

Comment: Please check this , I think this waht you mean, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winforms/thread/4326da39-4fa7-4f13-ac86-2e9828e4df48

Comment: You can add the Property in RichTextBox AllowDrop in Designer.cs   this.richTextBox1.AllowDrop = true;
            this.richTextBox1.DragDrop += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.textBox1_DragDrop);
            this.richTextBox1.DragEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DragEventHandler(this.textBox1_DragEnter);

Comment: Please set EnableAutoDragDrop = False for RichTextBox, thats why Icon placed in RichTextBox. i got it Working with ur Requirement

Comment: You can update your answer to be more clear by following [This link](http://encryptico.net/?902b11bab7551ec4#4hOyRadIjyFyAd2e5e+MNh1FVvQyWDJSzEHSRD15YjE=)

Comment: Sadly it seems this _always_ fires the TextChanged event right after the drop, which, in my app, always marks the opened file as 'modified' from the start.

Comment: Had to work around it by setting an "opened from drop" boolean, which made my TextChanged function first disable said boolean and then immediately abort. Pretty dirty, but there didn't seem to be much alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, **Kazankoph** is **incorrect** when he tells you there is no "**AllowDrop**."

He made this statement in 2013, and **AllowDrop** has existed since **NET Framework was released on 13 February 2002.** You'll find this at the link below.
In fact, it is code you can use in Vb.net as well. As for the "**EnableAutoDragDrop**" if you go to your form design and "**right-click**" on the RichTextBox and go to "**Properties**", you'll find that "**EnableAutoDragDrop**" is normally set at "False" and you have to set the properties manually to "True." I took a screenshot of my code just to prove that "**AllowDrop**" does exist. I am placing the code I use to Drag & Drop in the event you find it useful. Be sure to **EnableAutoDragDrop** in properties as explained above.

**Granted this is a C# question**, **he's backing for my statement of AllowDrop for C#, with an example:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.allowdrop?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
        AllowDrop = True

        AddHandler RichTextBox1.DragEnter, New DragEventHandler(AddressOf RichTextBox1_DragEnter)
        AddHandler RichTextBox1.DragDrop, New DragEventHandler(AddressOf RichTextBox1_DragEnter)

    End Sub


    'Drag Load RichTextBox1
    Private Sub RichTextBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)
        ' Loads the file into the control. 
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(CType(e.Data.GetData(Text), String), RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)

    End Sub


    'Drag Effects RichTextBox1
    Private Sub RichTextBox1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs)

        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
            CType(e, DragEventArgs).Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        Else
            CType(e, DragEventArgs).Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If

    End Sub
```