# Remove icon automatically by dropped file on RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

I set to `true` the `AllowDrop` implemented the `DragOver` and `DragDrop` events RichTextBox. On `DragDrop` event I load the dropped text files' contents on the RTB but it does add the icon of the file in RTB I'd to remove it:

[image]

Edit: Here's my code:

```
void msg_setup_dragDrop()
        {
            msg_textBox.AllowDrop = true;
```

msg_textBox.EnableAutoDragDrop = true;
                msg_textBox.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(msg_DragEnter);
                msg_textBox.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(msg_DragDrop);
            }

```
        void msg_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

        void msg_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = (string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string filename in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    string text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
                    buffer.Append(text);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errMsg = string.Format("cannot read the file\"{0}\" error: {1}", filename, ex.Message);
                    MessageBox.Show(errMsg, "Reading file error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
            }

            msg_textBox.Text = buffer.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dragging files into rich textbox to read text in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333457/dragging-files-into-rich-textbox-to-read-text-in-file)

Comment: No code, but are you opening the file and adding just the text or just accepting anything dropped?

Comment: @stuartd: I'll check out how is this code different from the mine. Thanks!

Comment: @Plutonix: Check out the edit. I added my code. I guess I'm just reading the file and appending the text. It used to work on TextBox just fine. How does it differ in RTB?

Comment: @dbc: Yes. I'll edit the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere you have set [`msg_textBox.EnableAutoDragDrop = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.enableautodragdrop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), either in your designer window or your code.  You need to set this to false.  You do still need to set [`AllowDrop = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.allowdrop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When set to true, the winforms [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides standard behaviors for drag-and-drop events, to which your custom handlers are *added*.  If you don't want the standard behavior, you have to completely roll your own handlers.  (The standard behavior for a dropped text file is OLE embedding.  If you double click on the icon, notepad launches.)

Comment: I had really `EnableAutoDragDrop` set to  `true`. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but after trying to find a solution for the same problem, I ended up with a work around/solution

The DragDrop Method should be:

```
private void RTB_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
{
    String[] filename = (String[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    RTB.Text = fileName[0]; //this is where the text is
}
```

Now, if you have a RTB TextChanged method defined (RTB is rich text box), get the RTB.Text, then set the RTB.Text.

This seems to erase the unwated icons in the RTB

Example:

```
private void RTB_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentText = RTB.Text.ToString();
    RTB.Text = currenText;
}
```

Note: You have to go to the RTB properties and click on the lightning bolt icon (Events) and point the TextChanged Event to the RTB_TextChanged method you defined. Or just double click on the EventName and it'll create a new method for you to complete the method.

Answer (score -2):

Icon placement; Occurs when the Msg_DragDrop method ends, depending on the e.Effect property.
Add this code to the end of the method=>
E.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

```
void msg_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)

    {
       //your code here


       
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;

    }
```

Comment: Please fix the format of the code above. Also, if you can add some details to the author about how this can help then would be nice.